# HERE Maps Info bubble not rendering correctly using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, here-api, heremaps

I'm currently developing a React application using HERE Maps Javascript SDK.

**My Problem:**
I want to open an info bubble on a marker when I click on it.

**Instead**
This strange artifact gets rendered, and the map ends up going kaputt:

[image]

Here is the relevant source code:

```js
const addEventsToMap = (events, H, hMap, ui) =>{
         let markers = [];
         events.map((el)=>{
          var icon = new H.map.DomIcon(svgMarkup),
           coords = {lat: el.Latitude, lng: el.Longitude},
           marker = new H.map.DomMarker(coords, {icon: icon});
           marker.setData("Hello world")
           marker.addEventListener('tap', event=>{
             const bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({lat:el.Latitude, lng:el.Longitude},
              {
               content: event.target.getData()
             })
             ui.addBubble(bubble);
           }, false)
          hMap.addObject(marker);
          console.log(el);
         })
     }
     
    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
      // `mapRef.current` will be `undefined` when this hook first runs; edge case that
      if (!mapRef.current) return;
      console.log(userLocation);
      const H = window.H;
      const platform = new H.service.Platform({
          apikey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
          app_id: "XXXXX"
      });
      const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
      const hMap = new H.Map(mapRef.current, defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
        center: { lat:userLocation.lat, lng: userLocation.lgn},
        zoom: 13,
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
      });

    var icon = new H.map.DomIcon(svgMarkup),
    coords = {lat: userLocation.lat, lng: userLocation.lgn},
    marker = new H.map.DomMarker(coords, {icon: icon});

    hMap.addObject(marker);
      
      //add initial events to be displayed
      
      const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(hMap));
  
      const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(hMap, defaultLayers);
      addEventsToMap(posts, H, hMap, ui);
    

      // This will act as a cleanup to run once this hook runs again.
      // This includes when the component un-mounts
      return () => {
        hMap.dispose();
      };
    }, [mapRef]);
```

**My attempted solution**
I tried passing a H.GeoPoint object as an argument to the InfoBubble, as `event.target.getPosition()` returns `getPosition is not a function`.

Would be really grateful if somebody would point me to the right direction!

**EDIT**

As it turns out the giant black artifact is the "close icon of the infobubble".
The following screenshot shows the content I want to be displayed:
[image]

Now the question is why is it getting rendered this way and is there a fix for it.

**As mentioned earlier I'm using the code provided by the HERE API documentation!**

Comment: That looks like an enormous check-mark. Something to do with the size?

Comment: @ParthShah exactly, this is what I get when I tap on the marker, which should be an info Bubble :D

Comment: Could you set up a sandbox? What does `icon` have? Or the SVG?

Comment: The icon contains an SVG which I found on the internet. I also tried to switch all markers to be the default ones, thinking that might be the problem, but to no avail, getting the same big checkmark on the screen..

Comment: Have you tried using a PNG instead? I think the issue may be with "an SVG which I found on the internet".

Comment: @mortred95 Tried using just the default marker representation which is a green marker, still getting the same result..

Comment: Bruh, ditch that out :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. You also probably noted that oyu don't have the UI menu available (a gigantic "+" -the zoom I guess- was also showing at map default generation).

**Solution** : if you installed `here-js-api` you need to import `here-js-api/styles/mapsjs-ui.css` in your code, or  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />` otherwise.

Works like a charm.

Comment: that was exactly what the problem was, it took me ages to figure it out why and the funny thing was that back then in the React documentation they didn't mention that you needed to link the css. :D